# Django uWSGI creates log file but the file is empty (works with development server)

Tags: python, django, logging, uwsgi

I am trying to set up my Django project with uWSGI. I have defined my log handlers in `settings.py` and they will write logs fine when I used the development server. However when I move to my production server using uWSGI, although the log file is created, it is empty.

My `settings.py` contains this:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('django_auth_ldap')
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
    'console': {
        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': '/tmp/zdebug.log',
            },
        },
        'loggers': {
            'django': {
                'handlers': ['console','file'],
                'level': os.getenv('DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL', 'INFO'),
            },
           'devices': {
               'handlers': ['console','file'],
               'level': 'INFO'
            },
           'stack_configs': {
                'handlers': ['console','file'],
                'level': 'INFO'
            },   
           'django_auth_ldap': {
                'handlers': ['console','file'],
                'level': 'INFO'
                },     
            },
  }
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your config is wrong. You've put `loggers` inside `handlers`, which violates the `LOGGING` structure. It should have the `handlers`, `loggers`, `filters` and `formatters` at the same level of a dict indentation:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': '/tmp/zdebug.log',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console','file'],
            'level': os.getenv('DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL', 'INFO'),
        },
       'devices': {
           'handlers': ['console','file'],
           'level': 'INFO'
        },
       'stack_configs': {
            'handlers': ['console','file'],
            'level': 'INFO'
        },   
       'django_auth_ldap': {
            'handlers': ['console','file'],
            'level': 'INFO'
        },
    },
}
```

The empty file you see is created on Django boot, and Django logs on your development server because it uses default loggers, disregarding malformed config.